# ListView drawable effect

Tags: android, listview

i am trying to make listview items like this

[image]

i have googled it but no help...so far i have achived this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:top="1dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:angle="90" android:color="#000000" />
                </shape> 
            </item>

            <item  android:top="4dp">
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#010a16" android:startColor="#010a16" />
                </shape>
            </item>      
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

EDIT:
layer effect is hardly visible in image but looks slight better in phone
    [image: enter code here]

but it doesnt show exactly same result as above... anyhelp?

Comment: Can you share how your layer list looks like?

Comment: try with change color and height of divider and make one view with `2 dp` height and white background (it's not white exactly) to top of you row with

Comment: i have edited post to show current effect

Comment: use a nine patch drawable to shadow top/bottom paets of your drawable

Comment: u mean nine patch as divider drawable?